# copy and insert data from one database server into another via link server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a link server. What I want is to get data from a table of another server, match it with my db table, insert if any record not exist and update if any record exist, using specified interval of time. 
Please refer me any stored procedure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to do it for two different databases on the same server?

Comment: i dont know. if i do i wouldnt ask here.

Comment: Use a [`MERGE` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). You can reference your linked-server database by `<linked-server>.<database-name>.<schema-name>.<table-name>`.